# latex latin modern bfseries font scale

Tags: latex, xelatex

I use

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
```

to set the section title heading as bold font, but i found the title scale is not look good, i would like to set `scale =0.9` or smaller only on title heading, how could i do that? my latex engine is xelatex. thanks for the help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\part}{\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{\makebox[2em] {\thepart}}{0.5em}{} 
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\color{red}}{\thechapter}{0.5em}{} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 

This line is Latin Modern font\\ 
This line is Latin Modern font\\ 
\bfseries{This line is Latin Modern font bold} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: thanks, i saw \bfseries make latin modern extend, is there any semi bold font for latin modern font? i will post MWE later.

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\part}{\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{\makebox[2em] {\thepart}}{0.5em}{} 
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\color{red}}{\thechapter}{0.5em}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


    This line is Latin Modern font\\
    This line is Latin Modern font\\
    \bfseries{This line is Latin Modern font bold}
\end{document}

Comment: As you are using xelatex, you could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444643/36296 to get a semibold font

Comment: Unrelated to the problem:  don't load the same package multiple times and don't use // for line breaks, better leave an empty line. Also `\bfseries` does not take an argument, so it should be `{\bfseries your text}` and not `\bfseries{...}`